# Iframe resize and cross site scripting

Tags: javascript, iframe, resize, xss

Here is the problem! I have an iframe that loads an external website. I want the iframe to resize to 100% based on the content height, so that I don't get a scrollbar. Setting iframe height to 100% does not work.

I came up with two solutions:

1. Set the document.domain property at both ends to the same domain,
   which gives the iframe content access to the parent window. The the
   resize method can be initiated from within the iframe.
2. Use HTML5 postMessage API to take appropriate action. I use to communicate between the two iframes.

Both these approaches are complex. Is there a simpler approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed another iframe into your iframe. If the source of that iframe is from the same domain,protocol and port as the top level iframe then it can access it through parent.parent

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem last year and found a solution that worked for me on this blog:
http://solidgone.org/Set-IFRAME-height-based-on-size-of-remotely-loaded-content

An updated version of that method can be found in his follow-up article: http://solidgone.org/Redux-Set-IFRAME-height-based-on-size-of-remotely-loaded-content

Like jack describes, the implementation requires an embedded iframe into your page with a source of the same parent domain.

I did have a small issue in FF. The solution can be found in the comments of the follow-up article.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to use this little project on github.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer